# Load list of items of p:selectOneMenu when opening the dropdown?

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I would like my p:selectOneMenu to reload items and show the options every time I click it to open the dropdown. Has anyone tried it? If so, how do?

Comment: I doubt it's technically possible (JSF doesn't have an specific event for that), also I think it won't end up in great user experience. Loading values require requesting the server, downloading the values again and rendering the component again. If you render the selection component once you've clicked the arrow it'll be reloaded again and closed. Also, if values are changing so frequently how do you verify it still exists when user sends the form?

Comment: Really values ​​will change constantly but I will control which user is editing the item from selectOneMenu does not currently allow another user to edit before. From the point of view of usability would think (if it worked or were possible) a good strategy for the need of the system in question.